# MySQL ManyToMany show duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, duplicates, duplicate-data

Please help write query.

I have three tables:

```
+-------------------+
| Patient           |
| PatientPhysician  |
| Physician         |
+-------------------+
```

Find *Patients* whose *FirstName*, *LastName* and *DoB* within one the *PhysicianOrganizationId* are the similar.

I will show you the data that you better understand the problem:

```
    mysql> SELECT pt.Id, pt.FirstName, pt.LastName, pt.DoB, ph.PhysicianOrganizationId
        -> FROM Patient pt, Physician ph, PatientPhysician pp
        -> WHERE pt.Id = pp.IdPatient AND ph.Id = pp.IdPhysician
        -> ORDER BY pt.Id;

+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
| Id | FirstName | LastName    | DoB        | PhysicianOrganizationId |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Mario     | Gotze       | 1989-01-09 |                     101 |
|  2 | Mario     | Gotze       | 1989-01-09 |                     102 |
|  3 | Mario     | Gotze       | 1989-01-09 |                     101 |
|  4 | Fillip    | Gotze       | 1989-01-09 |                     101 |
|  5 | Marco     | Rues        | 1988-09-12 |                     102 |
|  5 | Marco     | Rues        | 1988-09-12 |                     101 |
|  5 | Marco     | Rues        | 1988-09-12 |                     103 |
|  6 | Dimitri   | Payet       | 1986-10-10 |                     101 |
|  7 | Dimitri   | Payet       | 1986-10-10 |                     101 |
|  8 | Dimitri   | Payet       | 1986-10-10 |                     101 |
|  8 | Dimitri   | Payet       | 1986-10-10 |                     102 |
|  9 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     103 |
|  9 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     101 |
| 10 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     101 |
| 10 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     103 |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I wrote a query but it produces incorrect results:

```
SELECT
    pt.Id,
    pt.FirstName,
    pt.LastName,
    pt.DoB,
    ph.PhysicianOrganizationId

FROM Patient pt, Physician ph, PatientPhysician pp

WHERE pt.Id = pp.IdPatient AND ph.Id = pp.IdPhysician

GROUP BY pt.FirstName, pt.LastName, pt.DoB, ph.PhysicianOrganizationId

HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY pt.Id;
```

Results:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
| Id | FirstName | LastName    | DoB        | PhysicianOrganizationId |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Mario     | Gotze       | 1989-01-09 |                     101 | 
|  6 | Dimitri   | Payet       | 1986-10-10 |                     101 | 
|  9 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     103 |
|  9 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     101 |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
```

Me need this result:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
| Id | FirstName | LastName    | DoB        | PhysicianOrganizationId |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Mario     | Gotze       | 1989-01-09 |                     101 |
|  3 | Mario     | Gotze       | 1989-01-09 |                     101 |
|  6 | Dimitri   | Payet       | 1986-10-10 |                     101 |
|  7 | Dimitri   | Payet       | 1986-10-10 |                     101 |
|  8 | Dimitri   | Payet       | 1986-10-10 |                     101 |
|  9 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     103 |
|  9 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     101 |
| 10 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     103 |
| 10 | Zlatan    | Ibrahimovic | 1982-01-12 |                     101 |
+----+-----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------+
```

Tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pt.Id, tmp1.fname, tmp1.lname, tmp1.dob, tmp1.poid

FROM (

  SELECT pt.FirstName AS fname,
         pt.LastName AS lname,
         pt.DoB as dob,
         ph.PhysicianOrganizationId AS poid

  FROM Patient pt, Physician ph, PatientPhysician pp

  WHERE pt.Id = pp.IdPatient AND ph.Id = pp.IdPhysician

  GROUP BY fname, lname, dob, poid

  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS tmp1

JOIN Patient AS pt ON pt.FirstName = tmp1.fname AND pt.LastName = tmp1.lname AND pt.DoB = tmp1.dob

JOIN PatientPhysician AS pp ON pt.Id = pp.IdPatient

JOIN Physician AS ph ON ph.Id = pp.IdPhysician AND tmp1.poid = ph.PhysicianOrganizationId

ORDER BY pt.Id;
```

Comment: I'll make changes as you make small mistakes in words.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `pt.Id` to your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    pt.Id,
    pt.FirstName,
    pt.LastName,
    pt.DoB,
    ph.PhysicianOrganizationId
FROM
    Patient pt,
    Physician ph,
    PatientPhysician pp
WHERE
    pt.Id = pp.IdPatient
AND ph.Id = pp.IdPhysician
GROUP BY
    pt.Id,
    pt.FirstName,
    pt.LastName,
    pt.DoB,
    ph.PhysicianOrganizationId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY pt.Id;
```

N.B. I haven't tested the above SQL

Comment: I tried this query does not show any rows. "Empty set (0.00 sec)"